# Figuring out format of GPS coordinates and choosing projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, latitude-longitude, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have a list of GPS coordinates (they should be near the coast of Guinea) and I am not sure what format they are in. After I figure out the format they are in, I want to better understand the process I should use to decide on what projection to use. Note: I have zero information except for the approximate location.

As is:
(1) 1000350 1259062
(2) 959409  1258527

Here is what I've tried:
Assuming they were just in decimal degrees:
(1) 10.0035 -12.59062
(2) 9.59409 -12.58527

Assuming they were in d mm ss and that all the formatting was accidentally removed and doing a conversion to decimal degrees (D + M/60 + S/3600 = DD)
(1) 10.01388889 -13.00055556
(2) 10.09694444 -13.11305556

While both options seem to be close to what I think they should be, they still don't look quite right!

Comment: Do you have an approximate geographic area where these coordinates should be?

Comment: Could be UTM X & Y, but without a geographic area, there's no way to know which zone.

Comment: They should be near the southern coast in Guinea.

Comment: Why don't you plot the result you find (both as dec. deg and deg, min, sec) using a GIS software and see where they lie?  this is just to confirm if you have the right kind of projection.

Comment: I've done both using GCS WGS 1984. DMS seemed to be right, but wasn't perfect (there were some random points in water areas...) hence my concern.

Comment: Try DDMM.mmmm. That's a common GPS format.

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from also having to chose how to project my data after I've figured out the format they are in. I have zero information, so it would be useful if someone could layout step by step what I should be thinking about and how to make the best assumption.

Comment: mkennedy - there are only 6 or 7 numbers, so doesn't DDMM.mmmm not make sense?

Comment: DDMM.mm (plus or minus some m's to whatever your precision is) is called `Degrees Decimal Minutes` format.

Comment: As @Mintx says, the values could be, as an example 10 00.350 12 59.062 or 10.00583 12.98437. That would make sense when you say that DMS is close, but not quite.